# Spring Batch - how to generate Output file of a batch job as excel sheet

Tags: java, spring, excel, spring-batch

I have a simple spring batch program which reads data from a INPUT file and writes to OUTPUT file.

Input file is having 50000 records and my chunk size is 1000.

There are five columns in the input file viz. one, two, three, four, five

My requirement is to create a excel file (.xls file) as output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no out of the box support for creating excel files (.xls).  There are two options.

1. Create the output as a CSV file (FlatFileItemWriter) which then can
   be opened in excel. This is the simplest option and would be
   sufficient for most applications.
2. Other option is to implement a custom FileItemWriter that creates
   the excel file using some library like apache POI or jexl

Comment: I also thought of CSV as an option. But what if the column data itself is having 'comma' in it. How to tackle that scenario ??

Comment: It needs to be enclosed in double qoutes - you don't have to do it, spring batch has built in support for generating CSV - it handles all these cases.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Can you please elaborate a bit on it ?? Where should we put the double quotes ??

Answer (score 0):

If an CSV file is not enough you will need to implement your own ItemWriter that can use one of the available Excel libs (such as [JExcelApi](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) og [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/)) to write an "item" to an Excel file.

I would start by extending ItemWriter. Make sure you close the XLS file at the end.

See the [POI quick guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#NewWorkbook) for examples of creating new XLS documents.

Comment: Issue with using these libraries is, they handle data one row at a time (i think so!! ).. won't it be a big performance hit ???

Answer (score 0):

If u dont want to spend time in implementing your own excel writer, you can create CSV file using OOB csv writer, then create a tasklet to convert csv file to excel.
Regards

Answer (score -1):

There is a spring batch extension project that provides and Excel Reader and Writer out of the box - https://github.com/mdeinum/spring-batch-extensions/tree/master/spring-batch-excel

Underlying it supports both POI and JExcel - though the newer versions of excel work with POI

Comment: This Spring Batch extension contains ONLY an ItemReader implementations for Excel. OP requirement is to create file

Comment: Right, my bad. This project does not contain an item writer extension.